# Swipe not working in Chrome emulation mode

Tags: jquery, touch, swipe

I am developing an application utilizing a.o. Bootstrap carousel (3.0) and [touchSwipe plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin). I want to add swipe functionality for touch screens to switch between slides. I managed to reach a state where the swipe works in desktop mode, but does not if I turn on the Emulation mode in chrome DevTools. Chrome is set to start with --touch-events=enabled flag but it does not helpeither.

The page has meta viewport set correctly.

Any thoughts on what canbe missing?

Comment: Maybe testing it on a real touch screen. Don't you have a sub domain or a folder where you can test this stuff?

Comment: My goal is rather to discover how reliable DevTools are for emulation. When I turn on Emulate touch screen (cursor "touch") for [this jQuery Mobile example](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/) at the bottom the green rectangle does not change to blue, whereas run in desktop mode (Emulation off, cursor default) it does.

Comment: I know this is an old post but really a big thanks to @nuton for  --touch-events=enabled idea. It saved our time.